# Django validation - avoiding multiple full_cleans()

Tags: django, validation

I am new to Django, and after reading a bunch of docs/guides and googling stuff, I am still a little confused about the best practice way to do validation.

It seems like the best place to do validation is on the Model level, to ensure that it is always applied, regardless of where the data comes from (e.g. Django front-end, some JS server, API, etc). If I override the Model save() method in my base model to call full_clean(), that seems like the best way to guarantee that the saved data is always good.

However, I am running into various issues with this in my project. The obvious one is that Django's ModelForms call Model full_clean() already, so I end up calling it twice in this case. On top of that, there are other complications, for example:

- if there is a Model level method that saves a compound Model that has another Model inside it (e.g. Address inside some Account), I can't just save Address, because Account might fail validation afterwards. So I really need to validate both Models first, and only then save them (keep it transactional). But then, I need to call full_clean() to validate, and it's called again during save(), making it 3 times it's called now. This seems rather wasteful, especially since some validation methods hit the db (e.g. validate_unique).

One thing I was thinking about is to make full_clean() smarter, i.e. add some functionality to check if the Model has been changed since last time it was cleaned, and only run it again then, but this seems rather complicated in the sense that it might involve a lot of work for each Model.

Any suggestions on how to better handle this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may try various solutions but will be running into issues because the framework is just not designed that way. For example if the `save` method calls `full_clean` and consequently raises `ValidationError` how do you ensure that it is handled everywhere (serializers, admin)? Besides, you can still call `update` instead of save and bypass the validation.

I would recommend putting validation logic inside the clean method and let the `ModelForm` call it. If you are using `django-rest-framework` put the validation logic into a `Serializer`. If you will find yourself repeating validation logic, just abstract it away and reuse where needed. *Ensure the model is valid when `save` is called.*

Answer (score 0):

After reading a bunch of other stuff online about this, I've come to the same conclusion as @zxzak suggested. It's a bit confusing, because some people do advise to put validation invocations into the Model to ensure it's always used, but overall, the consensus seems to be that it's better to put calls to invoke validate into Forms and ModelForms.

This is a bit counter-intuitive for Django newcomers like myself, because we think of Forms as something on the presentation layer, coupled with the website HTML, but really, they can be thought of as an abstract intermediate layer between the model layer and something that provides data to it (website, API, file import). So if by convention, you always use Forms to transfer data between inputs and models, you pretty much guarantee within reason that validation will be done for your models.

Of course there are ways to get around that, but that's always the case anyway, if you don't follow established conventions and/or program badly. For example, on bulk create/updates, save() is not used anyway.

As long as you do things intelligently, and use Forms as described above, it should keep your data in good state. Any bad data introduced by business logic outside of that and saved directly to model without validation is likely to be bad as opposed to invalid, and so wouldn't be caught by validation anyway, and is likely to be caught by testing, as opposed to freeform data input from website/api/import.

Comment: Yea, I thought about this at one point... But what happens when you write from outside a form? For example, I have a script that saves or updates model objects in bulk. If the data doesn't entirely originate from a form, you lose validation or have to find other ways to enforce it. My solution right now is to keep clean() in the Model. This way it's always called by forms. And then if I'm writing from outside a Model, I explicitly call myModelObject.clean() as needed (for example in bulk updates). At any rate, I don't think there's a one-size-fits-all robust solution - they all have drawbacks.